# Don't show image in ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin

I have in my phone two folders **Card** and **Phone**. I create folder **MyPhone** in the folder **Card** and added in her an image **flap.png**. This image I want to show in the element ImageView. I want to use this variant. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```
button1.setOnClickListener {
 var intent: Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/MyPhoto/flap.png"),"image/*")
 imageView1.setImageURI(intent.data)
}
```

Comment: In this way you are sending implicit `Intent` to show your image with any app on device. Did you mean that? Or did you really need to show image in `ImageView` component inside your app?

Answer (score 0):

if you want only this image you can use below code

```
File imgFile = new  File("/mnt/sdcard/MyPhoto/flap.png");
if(imgFile.exists()){
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    imageView1.setImageBitmap(bm);
}else{
    Log.e("tag","FILE NOT EXIST")
}
```

Comment: please check your file exists in path

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: i mean file exist not permission check, by the way check my edited code. and if it don't work tell me which android you test in it

Comment: var path: String = "sdcard/MyPhoto/flap.png"

   var file: File = File(path)

   if(file.exists()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Yes!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    var bitmap: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath)
    imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
   }

Comment: file NOT exists in path

Comment: Card/MyPhoto/flap.png - really, in code - var path: String = "/mnt/sdcard/MyPhoto/flap.png"